# Use two major-mode-maps in the same buffer

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, major-mode

I've run into a few situations where it would be highly convenient to
have to have the keymap of one major-mode act as a fallback keymap for
another major-mode. For instance:

- I write a lot of LaTeX in some of my org documents, so it would be
  great to have `latex-mode` commands easily available while editing
  `org-mode`.
- I frequent an irc room with Markdown support, so it would also be
  nice to have `markdown-mode` keybinds added to `erc-mode`.

In both cases this extra keymap should act as a **fallback** (this why
I can't just use a minor mode for this). I don't want latex commands
to override any `org-mode` keys. What I want is:
*If a key is defined in `latex-mode-map` AND it is not defined in
`org-mode-map` then use the `latex-mode-map` binding*.

**Q:** How can I set a keymap as a fallback keymap for a major-mode?
**OR**
**Q:** How can copy keys from one major-mode-map to another, without overriding anything?

---

Just to be clear. I know I could define these keys one by one, but
it would be infinitely more convenient to have an automated solution.

Comment: Use a keymap merge.  See `make-composed-keymap`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This turned out to be simpler then expected. As suggested in the comments here and on the question:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'erc
  (require 'markdown-mode)
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (setq erc-mode-map
        (make-composed-keymap (cl-copy-list erc-mode-map)
                              markdown-mode-map)))
```

This will create a keymap which is a copy of `erc-mode-map` but which
also inherits from `markdown-mode-map`. So all `markdown` keys will be
shadowed whenever they collide with `erc` keys.

If you **do** want some keys of the fallback keymap to outshine the
main kemap, just disable them in main one.

```
(define-key erc-mode-map "\C-c\C-a" nil)
```

Comment: I've noticed that using `define-key` on the return value of `make-composed-keymap` can have unexpected side effects on the original keymaps, and I suspect the same might apply to this manually `appended` map.  If you want to use `define-key`, it seems to be safest to create a new keymap whose *parent* keymap is a composed keymap.

Comment: @JonO. Actually, I was very surprised to find out this does **not** happen here. If I do `(define-key erc-mode-map "\C-c\C-s" nil)`, the corresponding `markdown-mode` key will still be available **even** in erc buffers.

Comment: Malabarba: I believe your last comment no longer applies after that code change. The `make-composed-keymap` documentation says "a nil binding in MAPS overrides any corresponding binding in PARENT, but it does not override corresponding bindings in other keymaps of MAPS." As `markdown-mode-map` is PARENT in your example, I would expect that `nil` binding to inhibit the markdown binding?

Comment: @phils Yes, you're right. (I swear I tested it, tough. Guess it's getting late.)

Comment: My interpretation is that `(make-composed-keymap (list erc-mode-map markdown-mode-map))` *would* have the effect you'd described, however?

Comment: @Malabarba Does the text explanation (.. appending the cdr of one to the other..) above the edited code block still apply?

Comment: @kaushalmodi No, it doesn't. Fixing it now.

Comment: `cl-copy-list` will not really do what you want.  If you wanted to copy the keymap, then you should have used `copy-keymap`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Malabarba, you can use `make-composed-keymap` for that.  But If you really want the new keymap to inherit from both keymaps, such tht modifying the new keymap doesn't affect any of the other two keymaps, you need to do it in two steps:

```
(make-composed-keymap
 nil (make-composed-keymap (list erc-mode-map markdown-mode-map)))
```

This is because `define-key` can sometimes modify the maps passed as first argument of `make-composed-keymap` but not those passed as second.  I guess you should `M-x report-emacs-bug` and request that `make-composed-keymap` accept a *list* of keymaps as second argument, so you could just do

```
(make-composed-keymap nil (list erc-mode-map markdown-mode-map))
```